# Modal View changes dimensions of original view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, model-view-controller

I am specifying the dimensions of a UITabBarController, which is positioned at coordinates 0x 40y on the screen. I then call a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to view a contacts list. I was able to specifiy the location of the contacts list to match the position of the UITabBarController. However, I am having problems restoring the UITabBarController to the position that I specified when I dismss the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. The original UITabBarController dimensions are over ridden and the UITabBarController frame moves to 0x and 0y coordinates on my screen rather than the 0x 40y that I had specified in the delegate file.

Any suggestions of how I fix this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you present a view controller it's frame became 320x480 so when you dismiss it it's frame changes

Comment: You mean *full screen*, which is not necessarily 320 × 480.